# Typescript does not detect optional field is define after check by if

Tags: typescript

I have the code like bellow

```
  async patchMultiple(expenses: PatchExpenseDto[]) {
    const currentExpenses: Required<PatchExpenseDto>[] = []
    const newExpenses: PatchExpenseDto[] = []

    expenses.forEach(expense => {
      if (expense._id) {
        expense._id
        currentExpenses.push(expense) // typescript throw error here
      } else {
        newExpenses.push(expense)
      }
    })
  }
```

After check with `if(expense._id)` typescript still throw the error

```
Argument of type 'PatchExpenseDto' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Required<PatchExpenseDto>'.
  Types of property '_id' are incompatible.
    Type 'ObjectId | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObjectId'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObjectId'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript understands that the property in fact exists, but it cannot infer the type of the object using the `if` condition.

You can use a typeguard to get past this:

```
interface PatchExpenseDto  {
name : string;
_id? : string;
}
function expenseIsCurrent(expense: PatchExpenseDto): expense is Required<PatchExpenseDto> {
  return expense._id !== undefined;
}




const patchMultiple = (expenses: PatchExpenseDto[]) => {
    const currentExpenses: Required<PatchExpenseDto>[] = []
    const newExpenses: PatchExpenseDto[] = []

    expenses.forEach(expense => {
      if (expenseIsCurrent(expense)) {

        currentExpenses.push(expense) // typescript throw error here
      } else {
        newExpenses.push(expense)
      }
    })
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApzAgFgUQB4AOEIAzhACJgD2yyA3gLABQIcAtigFzIlhSgBzANzMA+sAAmAfmTde-EMOYBfZjACuIBGGBUQyCIWJkAkiQDC6qFGJgAFIaKkI3dJlxHnlKgEpuj4xRgEmQAJQgAR3VgGwkAHjdsfCcybwA+emZaGzArfQDnADpxCWQAQgBeCuRNCQgYUAgJESZVJmYO9qYEPV5kAgxsAFl1ABsdAlGUaodPMhJXQY8UimoAbQBdH2QKjMYmWloe0jBkBCsbcGTAhbDI6NiEpeuvajTNneRNrMPjvpAIAB3F7zRbuEGrKgfarfLqHAxzCAkQowKhQHCILCzFY7PY-eHAGDIbGBMyWay2EnOHzbfb4+FnC62CHIgjqEhYgpkbYAeh5yDAAE8iCQEPwCKcwFgoFRAQZrGjkFhoBB6bRlAZRmRMgcGbQAcDEaz2ZzET41cg2vDlObdW1mEA)